# 3D beam deflection

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, stress-strain, structural-beam

How can you get formula for 3-dimensional beam deflection at the free end of horizontal cantilever due to the cantilever's own gravitational load?

[image]

I assumed E= 160GPa, $\nu=0$, $\rho=2330kg/m^3$,

I tried to use this formula below, but it seems like there is height that I have to consider...

How do I start?
[image]

or, is it analytically not possible, and numerically obtainable?

Comment: The height $H$ is part of the calculation of $I$. You can find formulas for $I$ in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "There is a height I have to consider"

Yes, that is where the factor $I$ in the equation comes in. It is known as the second moment of area, and for a rectangular beam of width $w$ and height $h$ it is

$$I = \frac{h^3w}{12}$$

The rest then follows from the equation you found...

Comment: Oh, really? wow that was simple!

Comment: Note - @Gert basically said the same thing in his comment.